# Wordpress login httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, .net, wordpress, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to login to wordpress backstage, using httwebrequest and c#, but I can't do it. I have searched via the web and found that a lot of people have the same problem, but I can't find the right solution. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

```
string adres = "http://www.site.com";
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(adres + "wp-admin/");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1";
request.Method = "GET";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();


//POST
request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(adres + "/wp-login.php");
request.Method = "POST";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
string password = haslo;
string loginData = String.Format("loginform=&log=admin&pwd=password&testcookie=1&rememberme=forever&redirect_to=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(adres) + "wp-admin/&wp-submit=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("Zaloguj się"));

 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 byte[] loginDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginData);
 Stream postData = request.GetRequestStream();
 postData.Write(loginDataBytes, 0, loginDataBytes.Length);
 postData.Close();
 response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

 // NEXT GET
 request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(adres + "/wp-admin/");
 request.Method = "GET";
 request.CookieContainer = cookies;

 HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

 Stream response1Stream = response1.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(response1Stream);
 string input1 = reader1.ReadToEnd();
 response1.Close();
 richTextBox1.Text = input1;
```

I can't login -> after second "GET" request, I just get the login form, not the wordpress backstage homepage.

Comment: Please update your post with a description of what is actually occurring when you try this.

Comment: I don't get any errors, just I can't login -> after second "GET" request, I just get the login page, not the wordpress backstage homepage.

Comment: Not an answer to your questions but a) why are you trying to, and b) you could check out the JoeBlogs wrapper I wrote to perform XML RPC functions https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/joeblogs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few months ago, and after a hard search, I found nothing to help me solve it.

At the end, wrote my own code that solved the problem. It's a SSO (single sign on) between .NET Application and WordPress.

As is recurring, it has posted  on my personal blog (sorry, but it's in spanish).

I hope it helps you ... 
http://sordalion.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/sso-aspnet-to-wordpress-aspnet-to.html

Answer (score 0):

So there are two pitfalls, one is that due to the redirect, the login cookies are not set, and the second is due to the native cookie manager not being able to parse some of the cookies in the received `Set-Cookies` header.

To login into a `Wordpress` account via `WebRequest` you need to do the following two things:

1) Disable redirects on the `POST` request by setting `AllowAutoRedirect = false`

2) Parse the cookies manually from the `Set-Cookies` header and manually add them to the cookie container after the `POST` request succeeded.